# How can I quickly synchronize changed Exif tags of photos?

Tags: rsync, synchronization, exif

I have a big collection of raw photo files. On most of them I have changed the Exif Data for Dates and Time Zones. Now I want to synchronize these changes to a remote location.

I tried to use `rsync`. But by default `rsync` will send over the whole file instead of the small changed part. If I force `rsync` to use delta transfer by using the `--no-whole-file` option it is even slower than sending the whole file.

How can I synchronize only the Exif data to the remote location, since the rest of the files are untouched?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact you use RAW images you can set the EXIF info in `XMP` file (one per image) and then transfer those side files to the target storage. Something like can help you to extract EXIF and store it in XMP:

```
find /path -type f -name "*.CR2" |while read name; do exiftool -tagsfromfile $name  ${name%.*}.xmp; done
```

and then sync only XMP files with remote location.

You can add this to ensure you extract all the information:

```
exiftool -tagsfromfile $name -all:all ${name%.*}.xmp
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not extract all the tags, like `TimeZone` and `TimeZoneCity`. What i find a bit odd, since I used `exiftool` to edit those.   
I also would like to write the correct dates and times directly to the files. Because I think the times are rather important metadata, that should be saved in the files itself.   
But after this I will probably switch to `XMP` files, so synchronizations of other data, like tags, will be faster.

Comment: Did you try with `-all:all`?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. When I use `-all:all` the output is the same.